# Setting MaxPageSize for EmbeddableDocumentStore

Tags: ravendb

Seems that setting the Configuration for MaxPageSize inside the progrram does not work.
I know that it is bad practice, but i want to retrieve all distinct artists inside a Music Database collection and store it in a GUI Combo for selection and don't like to loop through bunch of 128 documents. The system is used standalone, so the performance impact isthe sameas a select * from a sql db.

i do this in my code:

```
      _store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
  {
            Configuration = new RavenConfiguration()
            {
                DataDirectory = @"Database\MusicDatabase\",
                RunInMemory = false,
                MaxPageSize = 300000
            }
  };
  _store.Initialize();
```

But i still get only 128 documents returned.
Tried to add a key to my App config file and also added a web.config file with Raven/MaxPageSize, but it seems to be ignored.

Any idea?

thanks,

Helmut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaxPageSize controls the max *limit*. And raising it is generally a bad idea.
If you don't specify how many items you want, however, we'll default to 128.

Comment: So that means i need to use Take() ?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go